# how to display multiple arraylist

Tags: android-studio

How can you remove these unwanted characters? I have tried to use the remove method as in the following but it does not work:

```
display.remove("[]");
display.remove(",");
```

My view:

[image]

Comment: loop through list before adding in view, and from string replace or substring, else filter it using linkedhashmap